# XRP full node getTransactions : error - error [ValidationError(instance.options.maxLedgerVersion is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1])]

Tags: ripple, xrp

I have set up a full node on my server. Everything is working but getTansactions is throwing error error - error [ValidationError(instance.options.maxLedgerVersion is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1])]

I tried passing "minLedgerVersion" from my getserverinfo function using the completeLedger values but it is not working and giving MissingLedgerHistoryError(Server is missing ledger history in the specified range)]

I observe completeLedger is giving me random values. I tried to split and use min/max ledger version but that is not working as the format is getting changed
Somitime it give like this
completeLedger ="54873243-54888233,54888334-54888352,54888587-54888604,54888706-54888755,54888921-54888922,54889023-54889061,54889170-54889190,54889347-54889402,54889506-54889562,54889665-54889950,54890141-54890169,54890448-54890460,54890561-54890582,54890694-54890732,54890868-54891060,54891231-54898249"

and some time "completeLedgers": "54873243-54888233,54888334",

How I can resolve this ?. getTransactions is supposed to work with address only and options are optional but it is not working. Please help.